# Rule that references not current node

Tags: 7, rules

When a user visits the homepage of our site I'd like to display a message, but only display it if they haven't viewed a particular (other) node yet. I can't find any data selector in the Rules module that allows me to specify the values from any node other than the current node. How should I do this?

In other words, I'd like to create a rule that evaluates the value in a particular node (one that can be directly identified like node/100) in its conditions. I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using Drupal 7, and Rules 7.x-2.7

Comment: Is this question confusing? I thought it would be a really straightforward answer, just like I thought this would be an easy thing to do with Rules.

Comment: Action: Fetch entity by id

Comment: But can you then use a value from that entity as a condition for carrying out another action?

Comment: Yes via [Rules components](https://www.drupal.org/node/1582182) or [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional)